# Integrating Yodlee Fastlink via PHP

Tags: php, iframe, oauth, integration, yodlee

I need assistance integrating Yodlee Fastlink into our web application.  As far as I can tell, I have all non-Fastlink functionality set up and working correctly (e.g. coBrandLogin, userSession, userRegistration) and saving to our database as needed.  However, I can't seem to figure out how to integrate Fastlink itself.  I've followed the "Integration Guide", and while I seem to successfully acquire oAuth credentials (manually via http://bit.ly/1LOhFmT), I can't seem to use the final constructed URL to invoke anything via web page or iframe.

At this point, in order to make sure I'm not missing anything, I'd appreciate an ELI5 high level overview of the steps necessary to achieve basic iframe success.  As mentioned, I have basic Yodlee functionality working, with IPs properly authorized, as well as Private and Public credentials provided by Yodlee themselves.  Also, the application is written in PHP so anything leaning in that direction would be most appreciated.

FYI, the last email I received from Yodlee tech support is that I need to write my own oAuth2 manager (or more likely acquire one http://oauth.net/2/) in PHP if I want to fully automate the Fastlink process.  They seem to provide very canned answers with little else.  I've also called them directly, but am awaiting a response from our Customer Success Manager.

Hopefully I'm just being amazingly obtuse and am missing something completely obvious.  Any assistance you can provide would be most appreciated.

Comment: @humble_coder-  It would be great if you can share the URL here or connect with Yodlee Support directly. Else you can also ping us over live chat present at developer.yodlee.com

Answer (score 2):

No worries it's not coming from you. We experienced the exact same problem with yodlee.. their documentation is very incomplete and sometimes even off.
The support only give you drop by drop and take a certain time to respond. We had to use a Customer Success Manager as well to get things moving and lost couple of weeks in our development.

When it comes to fastlink you have to implement the logic in the front ( don't ask me why, I found it very ugly ).
You have to do all your call to auth get your token ect from your API ( I believe you already made that work ), let me make a list of the step :

[From your api]
 - Cobran login
 - User login
 - Get Fast link token
 - ( here we created a step called get fast link data )

[From your front]
 - You have to submit a form with specific information ( that I'm sharing under this text ), our GetFastLinkData gives all the front it needs to load the iframe.

- Note, you can encrypt your data with some salt or something for security purpose, I leave that at your discretion.

Here is an example of the html/form you need to have on your front. Replace everything written in {} with your data to test.

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<title>Invoke FastLink 2.0</title>
<body>
<table>
<form action="https://consolidatedsdknode.yodlee.com/authenticate/{cobrand-to-replace}/?channelAppName=pfmmasterfl" method="POST">
    <tr>
        <td>FinAppId's</td>
        <td>::</td> 
        <td>    <input type="text" name="app" value="10003600"/>    </td>
    </tr>

    <tr>
        <td>UserSession</td>
        <td>::</td> 
        <td>    <input type="text" name="rsession" value="{rsession-hash-code}"/>    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Access Token</td>
        <td>::</td> 
        <td>    <input type="text" name="token" value="{fastlink-token}"/>    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>RedirectReq</td>
        <td>::</td> 
        <td>    <input type="text" name="redirectReq" value="true"/>    </td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Extra Params</td>
        <td>::</td> 
        <td>    <input type='text' name='extraParams' value='callback=https://www.google.co.in/'>    </td>
    </tr> 
</table>

    <input type="submit" name="Submit" />
</form>
</body>
</html>
```

You can save this HTML into a file and test it from there for a first approach.
Hope this helped someone out here.

I'm open for ideas on better implementation of this fastlink nightmare, tried a lot of things to make that works ;)

Comment: URL has been changed to `https://node.developer.yodlee.com/authenticate/restserver/`